# Shall we use poll() or select()?

Tags: c++, c, networking, network-programming, posix

I'm fully aware of the major differences between `poll()` and `select()`:

- `select()` only supports a fixed amount of file descriptors
- `select()` is supposedly supported on more systems
- `poll()` allows slightly more fine-grained control of event types
- `poll()` implementations may differ in certain details

However, they both accomplish the same task in roughly the same way. So:

Shall we use `poll()` or `select()`?

**EDIT:** I might add that I'm not interested in `epoll()` since portability is of concern to me. Furthermore, `libev(ent)` is not an option either, since I'm asking this question because I'm writing my own replacement library for `libev(ent)`.

Comment: The answer might be [`epoll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll).

Comment: `epoll()` is purely Linux-related. I should add that I put an emphasis on portability.

Comment: Have you considered `pselect`?

Comment: @Philip: You should probably add this to the question since there're hoards of `epoll` zealots running around recommending it with no understanding of its limitations or the extreme cases where it's actually beneficial.

Comment: Why are you making your own replacement for libev(ent)?

Comment: @Tom: Because I believe that (1) event-based network I/O is a good idea and (2) libev(ent) are bad solutions. They are bloated beyond repair and feel like a set of wrapper functions for the OS' socket library. I prefer to interact with an event lib in the following way: here are my events and their corresponding handlers, this is the address that you shall connect/bind to, now go for it.

Comment: @Tom: I'm interested in a clean, concise, small and easy-to-use interface that actually *saves* me work. In my lib, you add event handlers, call `dial()`, followed by `talk()`, and you are done. You don't even have to know anything about networking (and you can't make use of it anyway). All you have to care about is I/O.

Comment: That sounds fair. Just curious, do you have plans to open-source this?

Comment: @Tom: As part of another project, a `select()`-based version is already available as open source at http://code.google.com/p/5dev/source/browse/ in src/lib/nc.{ch}, but I have yet to release it as a stand-alone library with proper documentation. So far, the header file is the only documentation available. Are you interested in using this lib?

Comment: @Philip: mostly, I'm just curious about event-based I/O and server design, so I'm always interested in seeing how people improve on the event-based I/O libraries.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All remotely modern systems have `poll`, and it's a greatly superior interface to `select`/`pselect` in almost all ways:

- `poll` allows more fine-grained detection of status than `select`.
- `poll` does not have limits on the max file descriptor you can use (and more importantly, does not have critical vulnerabilities when you fail to check for file descriptors past the `FD_SETSIZE` limit).

The only disadvantages I can think of to using `poll` are that:

- unlike `pselect`, `poll` cannot atomically unmask/mask signals, so you can't use it for waiting for a set of events that includes both file descriptor activity and signals unless you resort to the self-pipe trick.
- `poll` only has millisecond resolution for the wait timeout, rather than microsecond (`select`) or nanosecond (`pselect`).

Certainly portability of `poll` is not a consideration anymore. Any system old enough to lack `poll` is full of so many vulnerabilities it should not be connected to a network.

In summary, unless you have very special needs (tiny timeout intervals, nasty signal interactions, scaling to millions of persistent connections, etc.) I would simply use `poll` and be done with it. As others have mentioned, `libevent` is also an option, but it's not clean/safe code (its use of `select` actually invokes dangerous UB trying to workaround the limitations of `select`!) and I find code that uses `libevent` is generally a lot more unnecessarily complicated than code that simply uses `poll` directly.

Comment: I have never seen `poll()` available on a Windows system.

Comment: I've never seen `select` available on a Windows system either, unless you mean the broken non-conformant function by the same name in winsock...

Comment: What is non-conformant about it? Other than it ignores the first parameter.

Comment: Under Windows, select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout) will immediately return an error code rather than sleeping for the time period specified by (timeout).  Also under Windows, the failure of an asynchronous TCP connect() attempt will be reported only via FD_ISSET(sockfd, &exceptionSet) whereas on all other OS's I've seen, it gets reported via FD_ISSET(sockfd, &writeSet).  It's possible to work around these differences of course, but it's annoying :)

Comment: Winsock if of course not posix conformant, but select is there if you need it. And also poll (since Vista, or Vista SP something). See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741669(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Winsock's `select` only works with sockets, not other kinds of file descriptors, making it rather useless...

Comment: By the way, if you do find a system that lacks `poll`, you can emulate most of the main features of `poll` using `select`. You'll still hit the fd limit of course, but I'd opt for using a clean standard interface and emulating it in terms of a more limited interface when it's missing any day over the alternative of putting a new abstraction layer on top of them both.

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing for GNU/Linux, you should look at epoll(7).

But for most cross platform support, you could look into using libevent.
http://libevent.org/

Actually, it is hard to recommend a single poll/select implementation without knowing the specifics of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pablo, you should be able to add comments now that you have over 50 reputation points. Remember to only use flags when moderator attention is needed.

Comment: -1 for recommending `epoll`. Not only is it non-portable, but it performs much worse in the (very common) situation where you're frequently adding and removing file descriptors from the list to poll since each modification operation takes a syscall and runtime is dominated by the number of syscalls. `epoll` is rather harmful anywhere except in gigantic-scale servers (tens or hundreds of thousands of clients) with persistent connections.

Answer (score 5):

I would actually recommend boost::asio, then you can try both implementations and test to see what suits your setup best.

Answer (score 2):

I would use libev or libevent. These libraries are cross-platform and abstract away the details of the underlying implementation (e.g. poll, select.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, I would recommend either `poll` or `::boost::asio`. I find libevent to be kind of cumbersome and it has all kinds of stuff in it that's oriented towards C and/or towards higher-level protocol handling in it.

I would not recommend `select`. I have seen implementations of `select` invisibly fail in weird and bizarre ways because the descriptor limit was exceeded. And the best you can do is to make it fail in an obvious way. Maybe this is very unlikely with your application, but I wouldn't chance it.

And nowadays `poll` is available almost everywhere `select` is. About the only place it isn't is Windows. But, IMHO, if you want cross-platform portability to that platform you are better off using a nice wrapper like `::boost::asio` that nicely wraps the most efficient OS technique.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's poll() has trouble with TTYs, IME.  Where portability is a concern select() might therefore be a better choice.